# What is/How to do Unification

Tags: logic, unification

I'm reviewing for a final exam on Monday, and I have a question I was unable to answer on a previous test. The professor's notes were horrendous, and I can't find anything better online. They all seem to talk way over my head.

For each of the following pairs of literals, determine whether or not they are unifiable. If they do, show the unifiers.

1. P(a), Q(g(x))
2. P(x), Q(g(a))

I have a feeling that it's insanely easy, as the prof (despite teaching horribly, gives easy enough questions) but I still have no idea what to do.

Comment: "The professor's notes were horrendous, and I can't find anything better online." I'm a dinosaur, but can't help thinking "Try your university library. Look at a *book* or two ...".

Comment: @PeterSmith I've seen a couple of textbooks, and they don't seem to help me at all either. They explain things in a way that is far too technical for me to grasp. I need examples of how to apply the algorithm, not just the algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no unification in either case, since whatever you substitute for $x$ (and perhaps $a$; you didn't state which symbols are variables to be substituted), the first expression of the pair will have $P$ as its outermost symbol and the second one will have $Q$.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: @sunflower: I guessed as much, but it would be considerably more helpful if you explained *why* you think it's wrong.

Comment: @sunflower: This is rather unconstructive -- you wrote two different answers, now you've deleted them both without ever replying to my comment under one of them; you've also removed what minimal explanation you'd given for your downvote on my answer, but apparently you haven't removed the downvote itself. I would appreciate a more interactive approach, and in particular an explanation of your downvote, all the more so since your deletion of your own answers seems to suggest that you now agree with my interpretation of the question.

Comment: So, if two predicates are different - in this case, P and Q, they cannot be unified?

Comment: @agent154: Yes. In a now deleted answer, sunflower gave a unification algorithm which has an explicit rule to that effect: "The unification of two functors with different name or arity fails." From your comment under the question it seems you have access to textbooks with unification algorithms. If you take a look at one of them, I expect you'll find a similar rule, or you can at least infer from the rules as a whole that they can never unify two predicates with different name or arity.